# How to pass script arguments to AWS Batch fetch-and-run

Tags: amazon-web-services, arguments, aws-batch

I am following [this tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/creating-a-simple-fetch-and-run-aws-batch-job/) to run a simple fetch-and-run example in AWS batch. However, I'm unable to pass arguments to the script fetched through this example.

The basic example will produce this execution:

```
export BATCH_FILE_TYPE="script"

export BATCH_FILE_S3_URL="s3://my-bucket/my-script"

fetch_and_run.sh script-from-s3 [ <script arguments> ]
```

where script arguments are only mentioned in:

> This shows that it supports two values for BATCH_FILE_TYPE, either “script” or “zip”. When you set “script”, it causes fetch_and_run.sh to download a single file and then execute it, in addition to passing in any further arguments to the script.

I tried passing them with AWS CLI through the `--parameters` and `--container-overrides` parameters (in the latter under the `command` key), however they are not received from the script.

I would like not to modify either my Dockerfile `ENTRYPOINT` for each run or the `fetch_and_run.sh` script, but I cannot understand how to achieve this differently.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Mixing [these example of job definitions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/example-job-definitions.html) I achieved it with `aws batch` using:

```
aws batch submit-job --job-name <job_name> --job-definition <job_def_name> \
  --job-queue <queue_name> \
  --container-overrides '{
    "command": ["<script-from-s3>", "Ref::param1", "Ref::param2"], \
    "environment": [ \
      {"name": "BATCH_FILE_S3_URL", "value": "<script-from-s3>"}, \
      {"name": "BATCH_FILE_TYPE", "value": "script"}]}' \
  --parameters '{"param1": "<param1>", "param2": "<param2>"}'
```

Comment: Epic answer, first place I've found a working solution, the exact syntax in the AWS CLI docs don't work

Comment: Note that it's crucial that you use the EXEC form of ENTRYPOINT ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/fetch_and_run.sh"] not the shell form.  The shell form ignores command line args

Comment: Thanks for posting this. I'm wondering why you couldn't just add the command-line args to the "command" property directly and avoid the "Ref::param" with --parameters.